# Why do I get the error "MessageEmbed is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript

I have a problem: when a new participant joins the server, my bot breaks down and gives me the error "MessageEmbed is not a constructor" . I have no idea what could be causing it. I used the latest version of discord.js v 14 and node v 18.
Here is the code for the script itself:

```
robot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
   const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'greeting');
   if (!channel) return;

   const embed = new MessageEmbed()

     .setColor('#0099ff') // Sets the stripe color
     .setTitle('Welcome to the server!') // Sets the title of the message
     .setDescription(`Hello ${member}, we're glad to see you!`) // Sets the message description
     .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL()) // Adds a new member's avatar
     .setTimestamp(); // Adds a timestamp

   channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
});
```

I tried testing my code using GPT, but it didn't reveal any problems with the code

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Comment: How do you import `MessageEmbed`?

Comment: I imported like this: const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

Comment: There is no MessageEmbed class in discord.js (if this is it: https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/general/welcome) but there is a Class Message (https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message) and a Class Embed (https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Embed). Are you sure you are not merging classes?

Comment: It's called now `EmbedBuilder`

Comment: Documentation of EmbedBuilder [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem. Do you have complete documentation for the new discord.js?